# How to retrieve a specific data from Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am designing a website where when the user comes and enters his email id, a corresponding value gets printed on the website.
I have the below data on my real-time firebase database.
How do I write a javascript function in my JS file so that when a user enters his/her email-id, the value of the total gets printed on the website?

[image]

I have tried something like this:

```
function getdata(){
var email=document.getElementById("email").value;
firebase.database().ref('0/'+email).once('value').then(function(snapshort){
    var total=snapshort.val().total;

    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML=total;
})}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to perform a [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) based on the `email` property of the node.

In that case, it'd be:

```
firebase.database().ref()
  .orderByChild("email")
  .equalTo(email)
  .once('value').then((results) => {
    results.forEach((snapshot) => {
      let total = snapshot.val().total;
      document.getElementById("total").innerHTML=total;
    });
  });
```

I recommend reading the Firebase Realtime Database [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) end-to-end, as it should answer many of the questions you may have about the API. A few hours spent there now, will save you many hours down the line.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did indeed refer to the documentation.